# Err: Cannot POST /api/success

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I am trying to send a POST request but it seems like the route isn't working based off the error. However, I get the value of req.body.entries logged in my console so it has to be working. When I send a GET request the browser sits and loads. The same thing happens in Postman. I am trying to figure out why I get an error on the POST request and the GET request sits. Thank you in advance.

index.js

```
const successRoute = require("./routes/success");
app.use("/api/success", successRoute);
```

success.js

```
router.get(
  "/",
  basicAuth({
    users: { username: "password" },
  }),
  async function (req, res) {
    try {
      const entry = await Entry.find({});
      res.sendStatus(entry);
    } catch (err) {
      res.sendStatus({ msg: "oops something went wrong" });
    }
  }
);

router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    //console.log(req.body);
    const { store, entries } = req.body;
    Entry.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: store },
      { $set: { entries: +req.body.entries } },
      { new: true },
      (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }

        console.log(req.body.entries);
        next();
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    const entry = new Entry({
      _id: store,
      entries: req.body.entries,
    });

    await entry.save();
    res.sendStatus(200);
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Does your success.js `export` the router object?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, inside your `router.post()`, you're not sending any response, you only call `next()`. I don't see any next route for the request.

I'd recommend something like this:

```js
router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    //console.log(req.body);
    const { store, entries } = req.body;
    Entry.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: store },
      { $set: { entries: +req.body.entries } },
      { new: true },
      (err, doc) => {
        // throw the error and catch later
        if (err)
          throw err;

        console.log(req.body.entries);

        // send response instead of calling next()
        res.sendStatus(200);
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    const entry = new Entry({
      _id: store,
      entries: req.body.entries,
    });

    await entry.save();

    // send response 
    res.sendStatus(200);
    // next(); // don't call next unless next route defined 
  }
});
```